# Unable to run CPLEX on Pulp in Python

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, cplex, pulp

I am trying to use Pulp to setup my LP model and solve it using CPLEX solver.
I have CPLEX installed with license on my laptop but getting the below error :

```
PulpSolverError: PuLP: cannot execute cplex.exe
```

Comment: You may want to consider using [docplex](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/optimization-modeling/modeling-for-python/) (a modeling language) or the [CPLEX Python API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex-module.html) instead as they are supported by IBM.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `cplex.exe` is in your `PATH` (see [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324)).

Alternately, you can set the `path` argument to the location of `cplex.exe` in the `CPLEX_CMD` constructor (see the [source code](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/pulp/apis/cplex_api.py)).